# Can't install Mongo gem - make failed, exit code 1

Tags: ruby, mongodb, makefile, rubygems

I've installed Ruby 2.4.0 on Windows via the [RubyInstaller](https://rubyinstaller.org/). Ruby works fine and I've been able to install all the gems I've wanted so far.

But I'm having issues installing the [mongo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver) gem. When I do `gem install mongo --no-rdoc --no-ri` I get the following error:

```
current directory: C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bson-4.2.2/ext/bson
C:/Ruby24/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170719-13960-1i1n5nq.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bson-4.2.2/ext/bson
make "DESTDIR=" clean
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

current directory: C:/Ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bson-4.2.2/ext/bson
make "DESTDIR="
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

make failed, exit code 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The bson gem is a dependency of mongo, which requires a working build environment to install. The officially supported build environment for RubyInstaller-2.4 and newer is [MSYS2](http://msys2.org). It can be installed on the last page of the installer or later per `ridk install` command. It's best to use the default options there.

Answer (score 0):

Installing this gem apparently needs a working C compiler and supporting programs (including make).  You probably have to install [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/) or [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/).